# CarrierWaveDirect passthrough uploading doesn't seem to be creating alternate :thumb version in s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave

I'm trying to get a thumbnail image saved to s3 once the original is saved, but it doesn't seem to work.  The original file is there, however.

My guess is that since s3 is being submitted the image directly, the thumbnail creation callback doesn't happen or something.

I've tried to doing a `.recreate_versions!`, and I even saw s3 doing some stuff that I would normally see on that invocation, but the `image.url(:thumb)` still gives link to 404 result.

Here's my uploader's code:

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader 

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
end

storage :fog

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Here's the template code that generates the direct submission form to s3:

```
<% badge.image_uid.success_action_redirect = "http://" + request.host_with_port + "/badge_builders/" + badge.badge_builder.id.to_s + "/edit" %>

<%= direct_upload_form_for badge.image_uid do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.file_field :image_uid, required: true  %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there no an elegant non-patchy solution? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think my instinct on the callbacks that seems correct.  Here's what fixed it (in the success_action_redirect logic):

```
if params[:key] #and @builder.badge.key.include? "${filename}"
  @builder.badge.key = params[:key]
  @builder.badge.save
  @builder.badge.image_uid.recreate_versions!
  @builder.badge.image_uid = @builder.badge.key
  @builder.badge.save
end
```